# Как запустить функцию в другом потоке PHP

Tags: php

Я хотел бы спросить, можно ли в php с помощью расширение pthreads каждый раз запускать функцию в другом потоке, например как в питоне: Thread(target=function, args=())
Заранее спасибо !

Comment: Есть 5 разных способов, выбирайте https://habr.com/ru/post/278755/

Comment: @Lexx918 И все 5 способов в статье сводятся к созданию дополнительных процессов ... А процессы - это слишком тяжело, что бы в них выносить потоки

Comment: Так то pthreads выглядят полегче. А еще прямо из доки pthreads есть отсылка к  parallel который выглядит более подходящим для запуска функции в потоке